# Sbt-assembly: How can i assemble all classes to a single fat jar for projects with dependence

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am using sbt-assembly to package my scala object, but I can't figure out how to assemble a fat jar for a project that aggregates and depends on many other projects.

For example, I have:

```
lazy val a = project in file("project-a")
lazy val poj = (project in file("project-poj")).dependsOn(a)
lazy val root = (project in  file(".")).aggregate(a, poj)
```

After sbt assembly, poj-assembly.jar and root-assembly.jar did not include scala classes in project a.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

`poj-assembly.jar` should include the classes from project a. Please provide a fully working example on Github if you observe otherwise, because that would be sbt-assembly bug.

Here's my demonstration.

#### demo

```
$ sbt
> poj/assembly
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /xxx/project-poj/target/scala-2.12/classes...
[info] Including: scala-library-2.12.1.jar
[info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[info] Merging files...
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to a file
[info] SHA-1: 58a67743530fef8d0713759060c685c536d29591
[info] Packaging /xxx/project-poj/target/scala-2.12/poj-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Jan 22, 2017 8:05:29 AM
> exit
$ java -jar project-poj/target/scala-2.12/poj-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
A(1)
```

As you see above, it says `A(1)`, which is a class I defined in project a. The following is the files in the build.

#### project/build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.13.13
```

#### project/assembly.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

#### build.sbt

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(a, poj)
  .settings(
    organization in ThisBuild := "com.example",
    scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12.1",
    version      in ThisBuild := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    name := "Hello"
  )

lazy val a = (project in file("project-a"))

lazy val poj = (project in file("project-poj"))
  .dependsOn(a)
```

#### project-a/A.scala

```
package example

case class A(a: Int)
```

#### project-poj/Hello.scala

```
package example

object Hello extends App {
  println(example.A(1))
}
```

Comment: Thank u for answer, today i set up a new project with some more detailed assemblyMergeStrategy, and i find  poj-assembly.jar has include scala classes in project a. I am not sure what happen, may be I made some mistake.

Comment: A new question is: the root-assembly.jar which I just added did not include classes in other projects. Is this a right behavior for sbt-assembly? Can I add all classed to the root project? thank u again .